# How to combine videos by aerender.exe

Tags: after-effects

I have video list, i want to combine this list by aerender.exe command line.

`./aerender -project file1.mov file2.mov file3.mov ... -output`

Is there any way to solve this problem. Help me.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i dont know command line to combine video list